# Conditional Sampling

Tags: r, conditional-statements, sampling

`enter code here`I'm completely new to R, basically I need to take a sample from a data set with specific conditions met. I need a test sample and a training set. Say that I have 100 trucks, 40 of them use gasoline and 60 of them use diesel. I need my training sample to be 90 trucks, 35 of them use gasoline and the rest use diesel. The rest of the trucks that were not used in the training sample will be used in the test sample. My problem is that I don't know how to exactly sample with this condition. I created a new column where if a truck uses gasoline it has a value of 1 and 0 if it has diesel. My thought is that I can sample with the condition that sum(trucks$gasoline)=35 , however I don't know how to input it in the R console as a condition. Can someone help?

```
45 12.74   9.79    9.37 gasoline     1
46 13.31   4.94   12.29 gasoline     1
47 16.90   5.85   13.28 gasoline     1
48 18.04   7.67   15.41 gasoline     1
49 10.15  12.28    8.05 gasoline     1
50 11.65  11.35    4.12 gasoline     1
51  8.50  12.26    9.11   diesel     0
52  7.42   5.13   17.15   diesel     0
53 10.28   3.32   11.23   diesel     0
54 10.16  14.72    5.99   diesel     0
55 12.79   4.17   29.28   diesel     0
56  9.60  12.72   11.00   diesel     0
57  6.47   8.89   19.00   diesel     0
58 11.35   9.95   14.53   diesel     0
```

Comment: Hi! although its easy enough to create these data, it is often helpful to post the data in a way that allows them to get the data immediately (e.g. dput or construct a data.frame) - also, do you want to sample randomly among certain types of gasoline or just take the first n that meet that condition?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your fuel type column is named `type`, and your dataset is called `data`, you can do the following:

```
# set data to data.table
data.table::setDT(data)

# add a row identifier, if you don't have one already
data[,id:=.I]

# generate training subset
train = rbind(
  data[type=="gasoline"][sample(seq(1,.N),35)],
  data[type=="diesel"][sample(1:55)]
)

# generate test set
test = data[!train, on="id"]
```

Here is the aggregated output, showing 90 trucks in the training set, 35 of which are gasoline, and the rest of which are diesel

```
> train[,.N, type]
       type  N
1: gasoline 35
2:   diesel 55

> test[,.N, type]
       type N
1: gasoline 5
2:   diesel 5
```